# Js paste file size is bigger input file

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, file

I use paste to handle a picture, the picture only 3.6m, but it change 23m after i paste the picture.

```
  document.addEventListener('paste', function (event) {
    var items = event.clipboardData && event.clipboardData.items;
    var file = null;
    if (items && items.length) {
        // 检索剪切板items
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
                file = items[i].getAsFile();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    console.error(file.size); // 23m
    // 此时file就是剪切板中的图片文件
});
```

I do not know why?

When i use input to handle it, the picture size is normal.

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file.size); // 3.6m
  })
```

A 3.6m image using paste API becomes 23m. If you use input mode to process or 3.6m, why？

Comment: How did you copy that image in the clipboard? Sounds like your system copied the raw pixels instead of the binary file.

Comment: I use comman + c to copy the picture in my mac. System copied? how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: from where did you use this shortcut? From the Finder? While selecting the image from an app? From a web page?

Comment: from my iphone, other picture has the same problem.

Comment: @Kaiido we have the same issue when doing Cmd + C. copying from the desktop. is there a way to copy the binary file and not raw pixels?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no... i do not why..

Comment: Same problem here.